# Pass array of objects with predefined keys as props to Vue 3 component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Defining an array as props for a Vue 3 component using the Composition API is simple...

```js
<script setup>

defineProps({
  items: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
});

</script>
```

Now this array should be an array of objects like the following. That's not a problem either.

```js
[
  {
    username: "foo",
    email: "foo@example.com"
  },
  {
    username: "bar",
    email: "bar@example.com"
  }
]
```

But is there a way to define that each object in the array must contain the properties `username` and `email`? So that someone using this component's props knows what the objects must look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the prop validator to check the array objects like:

```html
<script setup>

defineProps({
  items: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    validator(val){
       let isValidObj= val.every(obj=>obj.hasOwnProperty('username') && obj.hasOwnProperty('email') )
      if(!isValidObj){
         console.warn('The object should have username and email');
         return false
       }
      return true;
    }
  },
});

</script>
```